# How do I get the balance of an account on ThunderCore?

Tags: web3js, thundercore

I want to programmatically query the balance of an address or a list of addresses. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the balance of `0xc466c8ff5dAce08A09cFC63760f7Cc63734501C1` at the latest block, do:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xad23b02673214973e354d41e19999d9e01f3be58", "latest"], "id":1}' https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com/
```

Output: `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xde0b6b3a7640000"}`

Fetching the balance of a single account with [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/):

```
const Eth = require('web3-eth');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3Provider = () => {
  return Eth.giveProvider || 'https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com';
}
const balance = async (address) => {
  const eth = new Eth(web3Provider());
  return Web3.utils.fromWei(await eth.getBalance(address));
}
```

## Sample Session

```
const address = '0xc466c8ff5dAce08A09cFC63760f7Cc63734501C1';
await balance(address) // -> '1'
```

## Units

- `0xde0b6b3a7640000` equals `10**18`
- Using Ethereum terminology, [`fromWei`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-utils.html#fromwei) converts `10^18` Wei to `1` Ether, or using Thunder terminology
- Using ThunderCore terminology, [`fromWei`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-utils.html#fromwei) converts `10^18` Ella to `1` TT
- `fromWei(0xde0b6b3a7640000)` equals `fromWei(10**18)` equals `1`

## Batch Request to Query Balance

- For an array of addresses, you can use JSON-RPC 2.0's [Batch Requests](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#batch) to save network round trips
- When querying `https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com`, limit the batch size to around `30`

The following class wraps `web3.js-1.2.6`'s [`BatchRequest`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#batchrequest) and make it return a Javascript `Promise`:

```
class BatchRequest {
  constructor(web3) {
    this.b = new web3.BatchRequest();
    this.results = [];
    this.resolve = null;
    this.reject = null;
    this.resultsFilled = 0;
  }
  web3BatchRequestCallBack(index, err, result) {
    /* if any request in our batch fails, reject the promise we return from `execute` */
    if (err) {
      this.reject(new Error(`request ${index} failed: ${err}`))
      return;
    }
    this.results[index] = result;
    this.resultsFilled++;
    if (this.resultsFilled === this.results.length) {
      this.resolve(this.results);
    }
  }
  resultPromiseExecutor(resolve, reject) {
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  }
  add(method /* web3-core-method.Method */) {
    const index = this.results.length;
    method.callback = (err, result) => {
      this.web3BatchRequestCallBack(index, err, result)
    };
    this.b.add(method);
    this.results.push(undefined);
  }
  execute() /*: Promise */ {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { this.resultPromiseExecutor(resolve, reject) });
    /* must arrange for resultPromiseExecutor to be called before b.execute */
    this.b.execute();
    return p;
  }
}
```

```
const balanceBatch = async (addresses) => {
  const eth = new Eth(web3Provider());
  const b = new BatchRequest(eth);
  for (a of addresses) {
    b.add(eth.getBalance.request(a));
  }
  const ellaS = await b.execute();
  const ttS = [];
  for (e of ellaS) {
    ttS.push(Web3.utils.fromWei(e));
  }
  return ttS;
}
```

`batch-balance-test.js`

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
(async() => {
  const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com');
  const results = await balanceBatch([
    '0xc466c8ff5dAce08A09cFC63760f7Cc63734501C1',
    '0x4f3c8e20942461e2c3bdd8311ac57b0c222f2b82',
  ]);
  console.log('results:', results);
})();
```

### Sample Session

```
$ node batch-balance-test.js
results: [ '1', '84.309961496' ]
```

See the complete project setup [here](https://github.com/thundercore/field-support/tree/balance) in the `balance` branch of the `field-support` repo.